# Advantages to use Java on Solaris

Tags: java, solaris

On many forums I found that people use Solaris for their Java applications. 
I interested what are the main advantages of such combination?

My first assumption is that Solaris is very fast. 
I also found out that on Solaris it is possible to match one-to-one java threads with kernel threads - as I understand it results in again very fast thread creation.
Please correct me if I'm wrong and are there any other main points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Solaris gives you (as its Software not hardware) over Linux or Windows is greater system manageability and low level tracing like DTrace.

What you appear to be asking about is having more threads running concurrently which is a feature of the hardware. If you run Solaris x86 or Linux or Window on the same hardware you will have the same number of logical threads.  However if you run Solaris on some SPARC processors which have lots of logical threads (32 or more) running concurrently which reduces overhead if you have a need for that many threads.

The http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC_T3 process supports up to 512 logical threads across 16 cores.  This can really improve performance where you have a need for so many threads, e.g. using many blocking IO connections.

However if you need only one to six critical threads (and a bunch of non-critcal threads) a plain x64 processor will be much faster, and cheaper. (As it is designed to handle less threads faster and are mass produced on a larger scale)

Comment: fwiw, as of about a year ago, the solaris scheduler significantly outperformed the schedulers in rhel & suse when running on an x86 system with lots of cores (64 or more, e.g. a big nehelem-ex box) in our testing. Performance was pretty similar at smaller core counts.

Comment: @Matt that is interesting.  My experience of Solaris is that it has more stable, predictable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

We use Solaris for java applications at my workplace. I do not know about any exact performance advantage, but the reasons we decided to use Solaris were:

1. Solaris Service Management Facility (http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/sysadmin/2006/04/13/using-solaris-smf.html )
2. Ability to copy the entire zone backup to another box in case of HW failure.

We run application servers such as Weblogic, and it helps that SMF starts them back up if they crash for any reason. Also, we do backup of our zones at regular intervals, and from what I hear- the zone can be moved to another machine in case of HW failure, and the application back to normal.